# Python Selenium perform double_click() using with ActionChains more than once in the same test case

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I created a test suite in my project, I need to perform double_click() 5 times on different web elements in same page(and in same test case). After performing first double_click, second double_click() is performed on the same web element(first one). I try to use reset_actions() after performing first double_click() but it did not work too. I use selenium 3.8.1 version. Here is my example code:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.web = Webdriver()
    self.act = ActionChains(self.web)

def TestCase(self):
    self.web.switch_to.default_content()
    self.web.switch_to_frame('frame_ID')
    self.act.double_click(self.web.find_element_by_link_text("ID-1")).perform()
    ActionChains(self.web).reset_actions()

    # Check something and close opened pop-up

    self.act.double_click(self.web.find_element_by_link_text("ID-2")).perform()
    ActionChains(self.web).reset_actions()

    # Check something and close opened pop-up

    self.act.double_click(self.web.find_element_by_link_text("ID-3")).perform()
    ActionChains(self.web).reset_actions()

    # Check something and close opened pop-up

    self.act.double_click(self.web.find_element_by_link_text("ID-4")).perform()
    ActionChains(self.web).reset_actions()

    # Check something and close opened pop-up

    self.act.double_click(self.web.find_element_by_link_text("ID-5")).perform()
    ActionChains(self.web).reset_actions()

    # Check something and close opened pop-up

    def tearDown(self):
    self.web.quit()
```

Is there any way to use ActionChains double_click() more than once in the same test case?

Comment: Did you get any error/exception? You said that you close a popup after the double click, did you remember to switch back to the parent window?

Comment: No, I didn't get any exception or error. In every double_click() performing, it open same pop-up, I mean every time it double_click() to"ID-1". By the way, all web elements are located in the same frame.

Comment: Update the question with the HTML for the page

Comment: I can not do that because this project belong the company that I worked for, they have a strict rules for that. But I can assure the problem is not about frame or window. I tried to switch back to main frame every time(after closing pop-up window) but still it is not working.